# Can I turn off SASS RGB -> Color Name

Tags: css, sass

I have a CSS rule like this:

```
background: #fff url('/assets/img/file.png');
```

It is compiling to:

```
background: white url("/assets/img/file.png");
```

Is there any way to prevent it from converting it like that? There is JS on my page that looks for RGB values and I don't want to have to convert those strings to RGB in some hacky function.

Comment: Sass doesn't do this for me.. you sure sass is your problem?

Comment: This doesn't happen if we just do background: #FFF, without the image. Did you try that? What output style are you using?

Comment: I chanced upon this page because ms-filter does not recognize short-hex and `rake assets:precompile` always gives me short hex. There is a `ie-hex-str` function that people don't know about. Google that.

Comment: Sass 3.2.3 in mode `compressed` doesn't change the color notation, no matter if `#FFF` or `#FFFFFF`. Just in the other compile modes it's happening.

Comment: I think that this is [Issue #363 - Preserve author's color format](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/363).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, Sass will not convert literal color values from their hex values unless you are forcing Sass to interpolate with `#{}` or a variable.

Using interpolation will return the "to_sass" version of the value you're interested in. For example, `#{ #fff }` will interpolate to "white". This also happens during variable replacements: color literals are translated to Color objects when used as variables, then "to_sass"ed into your stylesheet.

Furthermore, you may specify the style option `compressed`, which will return the less byte-length version (i.e. `red` instead of `#f00`). Since `white` is 5 characters long and `#fff` is only 4, your rule will replace with `#fff` instead.

There is no way to turn off the reverse HTML4 color name conversion when using variables. As a work-around, you can declare color variables as a string, then use then in styles with the `unquote()` function.

```
$color: '#fff';
.white { color: unquote($color) }
```

Comment: Great answer, but it didn't appear to work for me (*Sass 3.2.3*) so perhaps something has changed.

Comment: Works for me in 3.2.3, no matter which compile mode f.e.: 
`$color: '#FFF';
.selector { background: unquote($color) url('/img/file.png'); }`