# Can I force compass to compile CSS with hex codes?

Tags: command-line, sass, compass-sass

I am using compass to compile css from sass files.  Here is my command line code

```
compass watch [path] --sass-dir sass --css-dir css --output-style nested --environment development --relative-assets --trace
```

The issue is for a

```
background-color: #ffffff
```

Compass is compiling the css to

```
background-color: white;
```

and in this instance for a 3rd party parser I need the hex code instead of the plain text "white."  Is there any way to force compass to use hex?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to Rito's comment below the answer can be found here for anyone with a similar issue: [Can I turn off SASS RGB -> Color Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611571/can-i-turn-off-sass-rgb-color-name)

Comment: Hi, this should help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611571/can-i-turn-off-sass-rgb-color-name

Comment: Thank you.  Searched for similar posts but failed to find this.