# How can I force Sass to output colors in hex format for Internet Explorer's DXImageTransform gradients?

Tags: internet-explorer, sass, mixins

I have this nifty mixin for doing gradients in SCSS.

```
@mixin gradient($from, $to) {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from($from), to($to));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  $from, $to);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{$from}', endColorstr='#{$to}');
}
```

The problem is that SCSS automagically changes my HEX value of `#FFFFFF` into the word `white`. The IE filters cannot handle this. They need fully formed HEX values. Is there a way to force SCSS not to convert my values? I would prefer not to rewrite my entire CSS file to accomodate this quirk.

Comment: Sme while ago, a poster here was trying to do exactly that - textify hex color values.  If only I could get you guys together..

Comment: I tried that fix (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611571/can-i-turn-off-sass-rgb-color-name). Unfortunately, it did not work for me. It seems silly that there is not an option in SASS to turn off the interpolation of HEX values. Most of the time I want a variable to remain consistent and predictable when I pass it through to a function/mixin

Comment: Would be useful to know which Sass version are you using.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (using CodeKit's built-in SCSS compiler) and I fixed it by using the [ie-hex-str](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#ie_hex_str-instance_method) function:

```
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($from)}', endColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($to)}');
```

Note that this will generate an eight digit hex number (RGBA) rather than the more common six digit RGB version, so if you are passing style values to JavaScript you'll need to make sure your JavaScript can handle the longer color codes.

This exact IE filter issue is covered in the [Sass reference manual](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#color_operations).